# _BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'table' in 'field list' with objection.js+mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, knex.js, objection.js

I using mysql database and objection.js for handling my database actions.When I am trying to insert values, I am getting R_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'table' in 'field list'. This is the code I am using for the insert data,

```
Modelclass.query()
    .insert( { storeId: xxxxxx,
itemLocalName: 'LSｽﾄﾚ',
itemCode: xxxxxx,
itemType: '',
skus: xxxxxx,
itemLevel: 'L2',
colorCode: '99',
colorName: 'Other',    
regionCode: 'jqs' } )
    .then(function () {
      console.log( 'inserted' );
    }).catch( function( err ) {          
      console.log( 'error while inserting, error : ' + err );
    });
```

and the generated query is:

```
insert into `sampleTable` (`colorCode`, `colorName`,   `itemCode`, `itemLevel`, 
`itemLocalName`, `itemType`, `regionCode`, `skus`, `storeId`, `table`) 
values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? )'
}
```

Error while inserting:

```
insert into `sampleTable` (`colorCode`, `colorName`,   `itemCode`, `itemLevel`, 
`itemLocalName`, `itemType`, `regionCode`, `skus`, `storeId`, `table`) 
values ('99', 'Other', 'xxxxxx', 'L2', 'LSｽﾄﾚ', '','jqs', 'xxxxxx', 'xxxxxx', 'sampleTable')
```

and the table field is included by the objection.js which is not there in my sampleTable

Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

There is something in your model definition that adds the `table` column. Objection doesn't do this. It is impossible to tell you what it is without seeing the model, but I have a couple of ideas:

1. If you have overridden the `$formatDatabaseJson` method, you may be adding that column by accident.
2. You have an enumerable getter property in the class that gets included.

Adding the model class definition to the question would provide better answers.